# Returning to post/<slug:pk_slug>/ once comment has been deleted

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I can delete comment 52 (see screenshot below). My difficulty is then taking the user back to the page localhost:8000/post/8/. I am currently using   `return render(request, 'blog/home.html')` as a temporary solution while I figure out the answer to my problem. I have included my code for views.py, I have a hash (#) in front of most of the lines of code. That represents my multiple failed attempts.

*views.py*

```
def delete_own_comment(request, pk):

  #template_name = 'post_detail.html'

  comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=pk)

  #comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post.id ,active=True)
  #comment_form=CommentForm()
  #post = Post.objects.filter(id=8).first()
  comment.delete()

  return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

  #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk_slug':comment.post}))


  #return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.id)
  #return render(request, template_name, {'comment_form': comment_form})

#'comments': comments,
```

*urls.py*

```
    path('post/<slug:pk_slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
```

*models.py*

```
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url= slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title 

def get_absolute_url(self):
    #return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk_slug': self.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):

#The foriegn key is linked to the ID field in the Post model
#id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
email = models.EmailField()
body = models.TextField() 
created_on= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
#id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['created_on']

def __str__(self):
    return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url= slugify(self.post)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

[image]

**Update**

I tried   `return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk_slug':comment.post.id})` and got the below error.

[image]

**Update 2**

I changed it from `post_detail` to `post-detail`.

[image]

Comment: Does this work?

return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk_slug':comment.post.id})

Comment: Note: you need to check if the user is deleting his own comment ```if comment.user == request.user: ```

Comment: Java_Man I have updated the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Hozayfa El Rifai in post_detail.html I have {% if comment.name == user.username %}

Comment: `return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk_slug':comment.post})`
Change it from 'post_detail' to 'post-detail' to match the url name

Comment: Now I am getting the error message 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: I have updated my original question.

Comment: try `return redirect('post-detail', comment.post.id)`

Comment: Now I am getting the error message name 'redirect' is not defined

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

Once I had imported redirect, everything started working correctly!

Comment: Your welcome. I will add it as an answer please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import:

`from django.shortcuts import redirect`

then add this as the return statement:

`return redirect('post-detail', comment.post.id)`

`comment.post.id` will get the actual id of the Post object that is related to the comment that is being deleted.